# python: urllib object cannot be accessed after the first for loop

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

The following codes does not work well since 'line1' does not exist. However, 'line' does exist. It seems that 'fhand' changed after the first for loop. If we comment out the first for loop, then the codes work very well.

Could anyone explain why this happens?

```
import urllib
fhand = urllib.urlopen('http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt')

# It is the following 2 lines that cause error
for line in fhand:
    print line.strip()

counts = dict()
for line1 in fhand:
    words = line1.split()

    for word in words:
        counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1

print counts
```

Comment: Looping through `fhand` the first time _consumes_ the data,  so there is none left for the second loop.  If you want to loop through it more than once, make your own copy of the data and loop through that.

Comment: Based on your comment, I found the post below which explains the behaviour of "file-like object" in detail. Hope this will help others: http://joseph-long.com/writing/file-like-objects-in-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urllib.urlopen` returns a generetor, which is exhausted by the first loop.

Either convert `fhand` to a list
(`fhand = list(urllib.urlopen('http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt'))`), or do everything inside the first loop (ie have only a single loop).